# Can't remove 1px line in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

The problem in IE7 (maybe in IE6 too). At the top of the document there is a gray line with height 1px. What can be the cause of it? All the margins and paddings are set to zero.

You can see the site [here](http://eservi.bakuforum-icd.az/)

Screenshot for them who can't see in browser: [image]

if you zoom in you will see 1px border around the page

**Folk! I think *@Dominik Kirschenhofer* is right. It's the browser's border, not page's. I opened even google.com, there was the same border too.**

Comment: Please make an screenshot and highlight it. Couldn't find it.

Comment: I have tried it with IE9 in IE7 mode and there is a little grey border around the page... but this is part of the browser not of the page!

Comment: I don't have IE7 here, but the question I'd ask is: how important is this to the site's layout? if it doesn't cause any problems, I'd just ignore it; IE7 is history.

Comment: @spudley! you can see with IE7 mode in IE9. It's little icon next to page reload icon

Comment: @dominik - are you sure that it's impossible to fix it?

Comment: @jumancy - in fact, I'm currently on a linux machine, so don't even have IE9 handy. But bear in mind that IE9's IE7 mode is not a 100% accurate copy of a real IE7. There are some significant differences between them.

Comment: @Spudley - I have a real IE7 too, so it shows the same

Comment: @jumancy - fair enough  :-)  (I felt it was important to mention because I was caught out badly by that a couple of years ago)

Answer (score 0):

IE7 is adding border to your site. Try adding `border:0px;` to your body.

Comment: Maybe the body is not getting the border. First find which element is getting the border and then apply the above style to it.

Comment: border apply the HTML document - the whole page

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to reset all attributes? first using this css?

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Also try to reset the html tag as well like this:

```
*, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

And also try to remove the `overflow: auto;` in your css first. [general.css line 2]

Comment: my dear friend, I wrote that all elements' margin and paddings are set to 0

Comment: if I remove overfolow:auto the scroll appears